# How to delete a Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, accounts

Is there any way that I can delete/remove my account? I cannot seem to find anything in my profile about deleting or removing my account.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: I went through and had a look but not seeing what is says. Edit the "About Me" section of your profile to say “please delete me” and If your account has never voted or posted more than once: non are showing up

Comment: You then need to click on the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) at the bottom of the page.